# what is laddr and raddr in handshake souce code of websocket

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, handshake

I am learning how websocket works in python 3.
I add print(sock) to def handshake of _handshake.py in websocket source to learn what is the message inside sock
And the result is sth like this:

```
Print out sock:<ssl.SSLSocket fd=508, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=0, proto=0, laddr=('192.168.1.2', 58730), raddr=('202.160.125.211', 443)>
```

I wonder what laddr and raddr is?
I know that is too basic but without solid background as me it appears complicated to understand
I have searched gg for those keywords but there is no explaination.

```
def handshake(sock, hostname, port, resource, **options):
    headers, key = _get_handshake_headers(resource, hostname, port, options)
    header_str = "\r\n".join(headers)
    send(sock, header_str)
    dump("request header", header_str)
    print("Print out sock:{}".format(sock))
    status, resp = _get_resp_headers(sock)
    if status in SUPPORTED_REDIRECT_STATUSES:
        return handshake_response(status, resp, None)
    success, subproto = _validate(resp, key, options.get("subprotocols"))
    if not success:
        raise WebSocketException("Invalid WebSocket Header")
    return handshake_response(status, resp, subproto)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`laddr` means local address and `raddr` means remote address of the socket. Depending on the context of the process or application, one address becomes the remote to the other socket.